# I can't get my JTable to show anything

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jscrollpane

I cant get my gui to show the Jtable, why i dont know and i dont get any error and when i print something to the screen i get 9 colum. so i get data. but what i'm doing wrong i have no idea about that.

My GUIOdreHandler looks like this

```
public GUIOrdreHandler(){

            KaldSQL ks = new KaldSQL();
            ResultSet rs;

        }

        public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
                throws SQLException {

            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

            // names of columns
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
                columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
                System.out.println(columnCount);
            }

            // data of the table
            Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                    vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
                }
                data.add(vector);
            }

            return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

            }
```

And my GUIHentOrdre looks like this

```
public GUIHentOrdre(){

        try {
            con = ks.connectNow();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        JPanel info = new JPanel();
        info.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        button = new JButton("button");
        info.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button);
        ResultSet rs = ks.Hentalleordreliste(con);
        GUIOrdreHandler gh = new GUIOrdreHandler();

        try {
            table = new JTable(gh.buildTableModel(rs));

            System.out.println(table);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        info.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(table);
    }
}
```

> I have tried anything google, book northing works, so please help me
>   :D

Comment: But i can see my button. when i call GUIHentOrdre().

Comment: info.setViewportView(table); did not work

Answer (score 1):

only about mistakes in your code

```
JPanel info = new JPanel();
info.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
button = new JButton("button");
info.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(button);
```

- remove code line about `add(button);` to the (code not exactly talking about)
- change `info.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);` to the `NORTH` or `SOUTH`
- you not added `JTable` (in `JScrollPane`) to the `JPanel` correctly

pseudo code

```
JPanel info = new JPanel();
info.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
button = new JButton("button");
info.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
JTable table = new JTable (ClassOrVoidOrModelNameReturnsTableModel)
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table)
info.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

- but this nothing above to solve something, because your issue should be some exception came from `JDBC`

  1. don't to create `JComponent`s inside `try` - `catch` block, prepare this `Object` before, better could be as `local variable`
  2. don't to create `XxxModel` for `JComponent`s inside `try` - `catch` block, prepare this `Object` before, better could be as `local variable`
  3. intialize `XxxModel` and its  `JComponent`, then to load data from `JDBC` to the `XxxModel`
  4. add `rs.close()` to the `finally` block (`try` - `catch` - `finally`)
- don't reinvent the wheel, use

  1. [ResultSetTableModel](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DatabaseBrowser.htm)
  2. [Table From Database by @camickr](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/)