# I get the Jtable but no data

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, resultset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can’t get my JTable to show anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732705/i-cant-get-my-jtable-to-show-anything)

I can show my Table but I can't get any data in the table, just the column name. My code looks like this.

```
public static DefaultTableModel buildTableModel(ResultSet rs)
            throws SQLException {

        java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();

        // names of columns
        Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();
        int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
            columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
        }

        // data of the table
        Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
            for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {

                vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));

            }
            data.add(vector);
        }

        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

    }
```

and my kaldSql looks like this.

```
public ResultSet Hentalleordreliste(Connection con){

    ResultSet Hentalleordreliste = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select varebestillinger.BestillingsID, " +
                "varebestillinger.LeverandoerID, "+
                "varebestillinger.BestillingsDato, varebestillinger.LeveringsDato, "+
                "varebestillinger.BestillingsStatus, varebestillinger.ModtagetAf, "+
                "varebestillinger.ModtagelsesDato, varebestillingsliste.Vare, " +
                "varebestillingsliste.Antal from varebestillinger left outer join " +
                "varebestillingsliste on  ListeID = BestillingsID");
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();


        while(rs.next()) {
            Hentalleordreliste = rs;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Hentalleordreliste;


}
```

and the GUI looks like this.

```
public GUIHentOrdre() {

    try {
        con = ks.connectNow();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    ResultSet rs = ks.Hentalleordreliste(con);
    GUIOrdreHandler gh = new GUIOrdreHandler();
    JTable table = null;
    try {
        table = new JTable(gh.buildTableModel(rs));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    JPanel info = new JPanel();
    info.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    LavBestilling = new JButton("Lav ny bestilling");
    TableModel ClassOrVoidOrModelNameReturnsTableModel = null;
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    info.setSize(1024, 768);
    add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(LavBestilling, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    LavBestilling.addActionListener(handler);

}
```

As told before, I can get the column name, I can create my table but cant get any data stored inside.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use code formatting on code samples.

Comment: Can you debug at data.add(vector); when you are adding data. Whether the data is successfully added or not.

Comment: it never run while (rs.next()) {
          Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
          for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
           
           vector.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
           
              
          }
          data.add(vector);
      }

Comment: in other words it doenst step into the while?

Comment: @user1880497 If it never runs in to the while loop then no data will be added. So the data list will be empty.

Comment: But can u tell, why it is not running the while-lopp ? becuase i cant, since i found out it was not running i have tried to figure it out. but i can't

Comment: If i wanna catch one one colum and change it value, so it doenst show one but a string instead. how do i do that

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using a database that supports cursors, I would take a look hard look at

```
while(rs.next()) {
    Hentalleordreliste = rs;
}
```

Which would suggest that you're exhausted the result BEFORE you've tried to populate the table model...

Comment: What will be your suggesten then?

Comment: If i remove the loop og type, i then get a error and if i type it in like this
if(rs.next()) {
    Hentalleordreliste = rs;
   }
i get same problem

Comment: If i remove the while and let the code look like this

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
   
hentalleVare = rs;

Comment: then i still don't get anything. so if i as u told me and then run it i only the the columname but no data

Comment: You may be getting an empty result set. Verify that there are actually rows being returned

Comment: If i type it as then i get the error
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 3 to TIMESTAMP.
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(.....);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
     Hentalleordreliste = rs;
     
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return Hentalleordreliste;

Comment: If i wanna catch one one colum and change it value, so it doenst show one but a string instead. how do i do that.

Comment: You could use something like `rs.getString(columnIndex)`

Comment: [still without progress...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732705/i-cant-get-my-jtable-to-show-anything)